# Можно ли воду употреблять в пищу?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я тут недавно зашла в тупик. Не пойму никак, можно ли написать, что воду употребляют в пищу? С одной стороны, мы ее употребляем внутрь, но с другой, пища ассоциируется с чем-то твердым.
Буду благодарна за подсказку.

Answer (score 1):

В воде нет калорий, и следовательно пищей её назвать вряд ли можно, так как сколько воды не выпьешь насыщения не будет. А вот более калорийными напитками (бульон, пиво) думаю питаться вполне можно.